# Which for loop format to use here?

Tags: loops, for-loop

Recently I had an interview in which I was asked to make a output of the following kind:

```
 9
 1
 8
 2
 7
 3
 6
 4
```

Now I hadn't practiced much but somehow managed to make this .
In which i use 2 variables `$i($i=1)` and `$num($num=9)`.
And make the condition `$i<5` and increase it by one till it reaches 5.

```
<?php
$num=9;
for($i=1;$i<5;$i++) {
    echo $num . "<br>". $i."<br>";
    $num--;
}
?>
```

Which gives the output I require. But there another way of doing it by using `$i` and `$j` as the variables. So I want to know which one is simpler and better.

```
<?php 
for($i=1,$j=9; $j>=6; $i++,$j--){
    echo($j."<br/>".$i."<br />");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generically this can be written as:

```
<?php
//Bounds
$upper = 9;
$lower = 1;

//Mid-point, use MOD 2 to add 1 for odd numbers
$mid = ( $upper + ( $upper % 2 ) ) / 2;


for( $i = $lower, $j = $upper; $i <= $mid && $j > $mid; $i++, $j-- )
{
    echo $j;
    echo "\n";
    echo $i;
    echo "\n";
}
```

It gets a little vague towards the end of the sequence. The sequence that you provided completely ignores the center/pivot number (5) and the above code does the same for an odd range of numbers but shows them for even ranges. If the goal is to always ignore the center one or two (odd or even) then you can change the second center condition in the `for` loop:

```
for( $i = $lower, $j = $upper; $i < $mid && $i !== $j; $i++, $j-- )
{
    echo $j;
    echo "\n";
    echo $i;
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: okay  thanks Chris i will try to make as many types of for loop examples i can practise

Comment: This isn't necessarily the _best_ loop to use for your specific sequence but it does show you edge cases a little more explicitly. I don't give tests for my interviews but if I did I'd be far more impressed if you asked questions such as "Do you want this specific sequence _only_ or do you want a generic equation that can take variable ranges?" For the former, whatever, that could just be a string without a loop. For the latter, you could ask "What about the center number? What if there's two centers? What if there's only two digits in the range?"

Answer (score 1):

This looks better for me

```
for ($i=1, $j=9; $i<5; $i++,$j--) {
  echo $j;
  echo "\n";
  echo $i;
  echo "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be preferable to run a loop that decrements from 9 and use a variable to track the number of iterations:

```
$count = 0;

for ($i = 9; $i >= 6; $i--)
{
    $count++;
    echo $i."\n";
    echo $count."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One variable solution

```
for($i=1; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo 10 - $i . "<br>". $i."<br>";
}
```